# How do I add obfs3 bridges in torrc?

Tags: configuration, obfsproxy

I have installed Tor on my Ubuntu system, not the Tor browser bundle.
Now, I am aware that one can add obfs3 bridges into `torrc` file.
How might I do this?

Answer (score 6):

First you need to install `obfsproxy` package. Then configure `torrc` file like @user263485 said:

```
 UseBridges 1
 # This works for Ubuntu Linux, adjust the path according to your platform
 ClientTransportPlugin obfs3, scramblesuit exec /usr/bin/obfsproxy managed
 Bridge obfs3 <ip:port> <key>
```

To obtain obfs3 bridges visit [BridgeDB](https://bridges.torproject.org/) (step 2) and instead of clicking the inviting *just give me bridges* button scroll down and specifically ask for **obfs3** type bridges. Restart tor and it should work, it just did for me.

**EDIT:**
Note that obfsproxy support also scamblesuit bridges, bridge syntax is the same

```
Bridge scramblesuit <ip:port> <key>
```

Answer (score 4):

Open torrc file.

After first two comment lines which start with # add:

> Bridge obfs3 `IP-address:port` `Fingerprint of bridge`

and save the file. For more information take a look at [freebsd-ports](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-ports/blob/master/security/obfsproxy/files/pkg-message.in)

Update: Do not post the bridges you use in public. It make it easier to track you. This is how your torrc should look like:

```
# This file was generated by Tor; if you edit it, comments will not be preserved
# The old torrc file was renamed to torrc.orig.1 or similar, and Tor will ignore it

Bridge obfs3 <IP-address 1:port 1> <Fingerprint of bridge 1>
Bridge obfs3 <IP-address 2:port 2> <Fingerprint of bridge 2>

DataDirectory C:\Program Files\Tor Browser\Data\Tor
DirReqStatistics 0
GeoIPFile C:\Program Files\Tor Browser\Data\Tor\geoip
GeoIPv6File C:\Program Files\Tor Browser\Data\Tor\geoip6
UseBridges 1
```

Comment: It didn't work!  After I add those bridges it says: [warn] We were supposed to connect to bridge '54.200.110.239:40872' using pluggable transport 'obfs3', but we can't find a pluggable transport proxy supporting 'obfs3'. This can happen if you haven't provided a ClientTransportPlugin line, or if your pluggable transport proxy stopped running.

Comment: Are you sure you are using obfs3 bridges? Where did you get your bridges from?

Comment: I got bridges from here                                           https://bridges.torproject.org/

Comment: I edited the answer so it contains more detail for your problem.