# ENVError while starting obfsproxy

Tags: configuration, ubuntu, pluggable-transports, obfsproxy

I tried to run tor in command line by running

```
service tor start
```

After seeing this message

```
 * Starting tor daemon...                                                [ OK ]
```

I tried to start "obfsproxy managed" but this error occurs:

```
pyptlib.config.EnvError: neither TOR_PT_{SERVER,CLIENT}_TRANSPORTS set
```

I used

```
export TOR_PT_CLIENT_TRANSPORTS="PATH"
```

to set the variable but after that other errors occur.

Should I set all these variables manually? Isn't there any mechanism to set them automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`obfsproxy` should be setup inside of torrc if you wish to use it with tor, it shouldn't be executed seperately. The `managed` flag indicates that the opening process will be "managing" it, in this case the opening process is your shell and it's not providing the required configuration parameters.

The process for adding obfs3 bridges is outlined in this answer: [How to add obfs3 bridges in torrc?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/6049/12737)

Comment: thanks. so what happens if i do not set this flag?

Comment: i wanna run obfsproxy for developing issues. should i follow the same instruction?

Comment: If you want to play around and experiment with Pluggable Transports then this is probably the document for you: https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/pt-spec.txt

Comment: yes thats it. thankyou :)