# The scary torrc

Tags: configuration, bridge, client, blocked-services, obfs4

I've been trying to set exit nodes and obfs4 bridge(country blocking tor) into my torrc file but I can't find a recent post about that or any beginner friendly explanation. Can anyone provide me with how to set exit node and how to set an obfs4 bridge with an example?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, backup your /etc/tor/torrc and revert to the original of something breaks.

```
cp /etc/tor/torrc/ /etc/tor/torrc.backup
```

All of the rest is in the [manual](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en).

> **Exit nodes:**
>
> ExitNodes node,node,… A list of identity fingerprints, country codes,
>   and address patterns of nodes to use as exit node---that is, a node
>   that delivers traffic for you outside the Tor network. See the
>   ExcludeNodes option for more information on how to specify nodes.
>
> Note that if you list too few nodes here, or if you exclude too many
>   exit nodes with ExcludeExitNodes, you can degrade functionality. For
>   example, if none of the exits you list allows traffic on port 80 or
>   443, you won’t be able to browse the web.
>
> Note also that not every circuit is used to deliver traffic outside of
>   the Tor network. It is normal to see non-exit circuits (such as those
>   used to connect to hidden services, those that do directory fetches,
>   those used for relay reachability self-tests, and so on) that end at a
>   non-exit node. To keep a node from being used entirely, see
>   ExcludeNodes and StrictNodes.
>
> The ExcludeNodes option overrides this option: any node listed in both
>   ExitNodes and ExcludeNodes is treated as excluded.
>
> The .exit address notation, if enabled via MapAddress, overrides this
>   option.

So, add something liek the following into your torrc:

```
ExitNodes tor1.example.com,tor2.example.com,tor3.example.com
```

Bridges are already answered [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3924/how-to-add-obfs3-bridges-in-torrc#6049).